# Facebook Integration using angular js in php

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, facebook

I'm new to angularJS and just want to integrate facebook, I copied the sample code from facebook integration page but didn't get anything. My code is as below ->

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Angular JS Facebook Intergration</title>
        <script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>      
        <script src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app='fbApp'>      
        <div ng-controller="fbController">
            {{getMyLastName()}}
        </div>
        <script> 
            window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                FB.init({ 
                  appId: 'XXXXXXX',
                  status: true, 
                  cookie: true, 
                  xfbml: true,
                  version: 'v2.4'
                });
            };
            var fbApp = angular.module("fbApp", []);
            fbApp.controller('fbController',function($scope){
                    $scope.getMyLastName = function() {
                       facebookService.getMyLastName() 
                         .then(function(response) {
                           $scope.last_name = response.last_name;
                         }
                       );
                    };
            });
            fbApp.factory('facebookService', function($q) {
                return {
                    getMyLastName: function() {
                        var deferred = $q.defer();
                        FB.api('/me', {
                            fields: 'last_name'
                        }, function(response) {
                            if (!response || response.error) {
                                deferred.reject('Error occured');
                            } else {
                                deferred.resolve(response);
                            }
                        });
                        return deferred.promise;
                    }
                }
            });
        </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

`output: {{getMyLastName()}}` , Please Help me , (This example is just for learning) , Thanks in advance.

Comment: What error message do you get in your console? Your controller isn't compiling because you didn't inject `facebookService`.

Comment: "Error: facebookService is not defined
$scope.getMyLastName@http://192.168.10.64/yatindra/angular/:24:9
ib.prototype.functionCall/<@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:198:291
h/<@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:107:415

Comment: how do i inject facebookService ???? @georgeawg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how do i inject facebookService ????

You need to add it as an argument to your controller function:

```
       fbApp.controller('fbController',function($scope, facebookService){
                $scope.getMyLastName = function() {
                   facebookService.getMyLastName() 
                     .then(function(response) {
                       $scope.last_name = response.last_name;
                     }
                   );
                };
        });
```

Comment: Great!!!! **facebookService is not defined error solved** , now its showing another error : Error: init not called with valid version
Error
    at Object.a (sdk.js:42)
    at window.FB.require (sdk.js:11)
    at window.FB.require (sdk.js:11)
    at window.FB.require (sdk.js:11)
    at window.FB.require (sdk.js:11)
    at window.FB.require (sdk.js:11)
    at window.FB.require (sdk.js:11)
    at window.FB.require (sdk.js:11)
    at window.FB.require (sdk.js:11)
    at window.FB.require (sdk.js:11)

Comment: Go check your app dashboard, to see what the minimal API version your app can use is. If your app was created after API v2.5 was announced, then you can not “downgrade” to older API versions, and have to use `version: 'v2.5'` in your `FB.init` call.